# Getting Error "...does not have a name type" for Something that Does

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development

I'm currently working on a little text-based RPG here, and I've run into an issue. I'm in the process of making a class that contains all the weapons in the game (perhaps there are better ways to go about making a list of weapons, but this is the route that I've chosen). My current code for this is:

```
#ifndef LISTOFWEAPONS_H
#define LISTOFWEAPONS_H

#include "Weapon.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ListOfWeapons
{
public:
    ListOfWeapons();

    //BASIC (starter) WEAPONS
    //----------------------------------------
    Weapon iron_axe(common, axe, "Iron Axe", 1);
    Weapon iron_sword(common, sword, "Iron Sword", 1);
    Weapon iron_mace(common, mace, "Iron Mace", 1);
    Weapon iron_spear(common, spear, "Iron Spear", 1);
    Weapon iron_staff(common, staff, "Iron Staff", 1);
    Weapon iron_dagger(common, dagger, "Iron Dagger", 1);
    Weapon wood_bow(common, bow, "Wood Bow", 1);
    Weapon wood_crossbow(common, crossbow, "Wood Crossbow", 1);
    Weapon iron_throwing_knife(common, thrown, "Iron Throwing Knife", 1);
    Weapon blunderbuss(common, gun, "Blunderbuss", 1);
    //----------------------------------------

protected:

private:
};

#endif // LISTOFWEAPONS_H
```

Now, when I compile this code, I get the error `error: 'Weapon' does not name a type`. Weapon is a class of its own, and compiles and works completely fine; so my question is, what on earth am I doing wrong here? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does `Weapon.h` also `#include` the header file you've shown? This might be a circular dependency problem

Comment: @themachomuchacho Please post "Weapon.h" so we have all the code.

Comment: Might be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: You will be much happier in the future if you learn to not use `using namespace std;` in header files, especially those that do not benefit at all from it.

Comment: You do not use anything based on iostreams in this header file, and should not include it. You also should practically never use `using` for namespaces in a header file.

Comment: (Also, if you use a class to store these, they should be `static` so you don’t need to create a new `ListOfWeapons` every time, and either way they should probably be `const`.)

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Hey guys! Sorry, I should've mentioned: it is NOT a circular dependency issue; I checked and double checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ListOfWeapons
{
public:
    ListOfWeapons()
        // This is the constructor's "initializer list".
        : iron_axe(common, axe, "Iron Axe", 1),
          iron_sword(common, sword, "Iron Sword", 1)
          // ... 
    {

    }


    //BASIC (starter) WEAPONS
    //----------------------------------------
    Weapon iron_axe;
    Weapon iron_sword;
    // ...
    //----------------------------------------
};
```

The point is your Weapon member variables are initialized in the wrong place.

When you have member variables which need to be initialized during the construction, initializer list is always the best place to do it.

Consider a simpler example:

```
class Person {
public:
  Person() : age_(0) {}
  Person(const std::string& name, int age) : name_(name), age_(age) {}

private:
  std::string name_;
  int age_;
};
```

Class `Person` has two member variables and two constructors. The first constructor is called "default" because it doesn't take any parameters, while the second one is a normal constructor where you can specify name and age for the new Person object.

```
Person person1;  // 1st constructor
Person person2("Adam", 26);  // 2nd constructor
```

You can initialize some types of member variables where you declare them. But this only applies to primitives (int, bool, etc.). In your example, `Weapon` is not a primitive type so you cannot just initialize when you declare them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you, by chance, be able to give a little more detail? Like, where should I initialize them? I'm sorry; I'm pretty darn new to c++ still (I've only taken two semester's worth)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is it clear for you right now?

Comment: Yeah, thanks man! I really appreciate it, and I'll give it a go!

Answer (score -3):

you define a class name Listofweapon, but not define a class name Weapon

Comment: You didn't notice weapon.h is included?

Comment: clearly, that head file doesn't contain Weapon class,too

Comment: Clearly you can't answer the question without seeing it. You've simply restated the OPs problem. This is not an answer.

Comment: The commenters on the question directly assume it's a different problem. Either way we don't know until we see `Weapon.h`.